# TypeError: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a webpage that writes javascript arrays into a mySql table using ajax to call .php scripts. When I click on my div (.button) I get this error from jQuery.min library - `TypeError: Illegal constructor.`, never seen it before. Any idea what's wrong? Didn't put up a fiddle, since there's a .php file, uploaded whole thing to [here](http://topdeckandwreck.com/mySql%20shenanigans/) if you want to see it in action. Thanks for the help

html:

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>
tis just a blank page to get scripts and whatnot
<br>
<br>
<div class="button">CLICK</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
var strings = [];

for(x=0;x<45;x++) {
    strings.push([1,2,3]);
}

$('.button').click(function() {
    makeAjaxRequest();
    });

function makeAjaxRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'write.php',   //where I'm sending data
        type: 'get',    //data type post/get
        data: {name: $(strings)},   //The data to be send in a query string format or JSON
        success: function(response) { //A callback function to be executed is the request was succesful. A ‘response’ variable will be returned.
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

php:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "topdecka_wtAdmin";
$password = "OnlyWr1te";
$dbname = "topdecka_writeTest";

$data = "%".$_GET['name']."%";  //data passed from strings variable
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE strings (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    strings TEXT NOT NULL,
    INSERT INTO strings (strings)
    VALUES ('$data')    
    )";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);

    echo "Table string created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: `data: {name: $(strings)},` <-- makes no sense

Comment: change data: {name: $(strings)}, as data: {name: strings},

Comment: You probably want something like `data: JSON.stringify(strings)` judging by the comment by that line.

Comment: changed it to `data: {name: JSON.stringify(strings)},` , as I'm calling it by using name in my php later on, works without errors now, thanks

Comment: if you want to, write it up as an anwser and I'll accept it, or I'll just close the post in a bit

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič "or I'll just close the post in a bit", maybe just add your own anser